# Keep objects in place when scroll view is used

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, textfield

I posted this a few days ago, but can't seem to find a solution that works.

(1)This is the overall layout of the screen. The button is inside the scroll view, so that when the appears the button will be pushed up to the users view. Then back down when the first responder resigns. I **don't** want the text fields to move at all. I want to keep them in the location I placed them. Only the button is what I want to move.

(1) https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8iJy.png

(2) The result of what it looks like when the keyboard appears. It ends up pushing the text fields out of view.

(2) https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDhdI.png

This is the code that I am using:
    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollView: UIScrollView!

```
@IBOutlet weak var TextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var testButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var testView: UIView!
func closeKeyboard(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    closeKeyboard()
}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(scrollviewtest.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(scrollviewtest.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    }

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a scrollview? Why not just add a bottom constraint from the button to the superview then animate a change in this upon keyboard notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
```

in

```
keyboardWillShow
```

You have to create NSLayoutConstraint for button bottom to scroll view bottom, and then operate with this constraint. Code will look like this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
.... 

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.buttonBottomConstraint.constant -= keyboardSize.height
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.buttonBottomConstraint.constant += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

Constraint will looks lijke this:

[image]